# div gets pushed down for apparently no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple grid with 5 divs, each one containing an image.

Why the last div (with the different image) has an offset? It gets pushed down for no apparent reason.

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6dDpOi1VHIwsEY6OvIOC?p=preview).

CSS

```
.thumb-container {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript

```
  $.when( loadImageSet(imageURLs) ).then(function(data){

    var imageSet = [];

        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            imageSet.push(value);
        })

    for (var i = 0; i < imageSet.length; i++) {

        var thumbContainer = $('<div>',
          {class: 'thumb-container'});

        img = resizeImage(imageSet[i], 100);
        thumbContainer.append(img);
        $('.box').append(thumbContainer);
    }
  });
```

**EDIT**

I got it, I need to set `vertical-align: top` to .thumb-container or `display:block` to the img. But still don't understand why it behaves that way.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by pushed down. Do you need to have `<div class="clearBoth"></div>` at the end?

Comment: Because the image is not the same size. All the images are 90x100 , but the last one is 100x50

Comment: @LuisP.A. I would understand that if the image had the height bigger than the box, but that's not the case..

Comment: Its an eccentricity of inline-block you can look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your elements are `inline-block` elements they will be vertically aligned to the baseline by default.  As one of your elements is a different size from the others this is causing a box to appear lower.  By setting them to `vertical-align:top` it solves this issue

[See this post for more information about inline-block alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827977/css-unexpected-vertical-position-of-inline-block-elements)

By adding `display:block` to the image it will remove the extra space added after the image and thus will make all your `.thumb-container` elements the same height again

[See this post about the space after the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know!

Answer (score 3):

> img {
>       display: block; }

Just add this line.

Regards D.

Comment: Vertical-align: top is not a better solution, of course you can use it, but making the image tag as block, will take the full width ideally, and making it adjust in box.

Comment: If he can fix it without changing the display type and therefore doing float: left that is alright isn't it?

Comment: Yes float: left; seems like a better idea.

Comment: yes, float: left is also a solution, but float property is sometimes risky, as it pushes the image everytime to the left, even if there is another tag next to it. Float mostly not preferable by all.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) for floating issues.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change the css another solution could be to add a div with fixed  height  and with inside the .thumb-container

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why but the javascrip altering the size of the image also alters where the box is positioned.

```
function resizeImage(image, size){
var w = image.width;
var h = image.height;

// resize width and make height proportional
var nh = size;
var nw = w*size/h;
if (nw > 100)
{
  nw = 100;
}


// if height > size, resize height and make width proportional
if (nh > size){
    nh = size;
    nw = w*size/h;
}

image.width = nw;
image.height = nh;

return image;
```

}

Change the resize function to that and it works, not the best but it works.